# How to add the result of a formula to another in excel?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have 2 sheets

the first sheet has columns: code, description and price. So col a, b and c.

In the second sheet I have columns a and b: that represent the description and price.

So what I want to do is type in the code(which is the cell of the description in sheet2 e.g. a1) and then the description and price should be automatically entered into b and c columns in sheet1.

I tried following formulas but I get syntax errors, but it should help you to see what I'm trying to achieve.

In the description cell: **Sheet2!Sheet1!a1** *// a1 is the code cell, this formula is inserted into b1.*

Also tried: **Sheet2!(=Sheet1!a1)**
and: **Sheet2!&Sheet1!a1**

[Sheet1 (red is where i need formulas)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DbbtR.png)

[image]

[Sheet2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cc3ln.png)

[image]

Comment: A visual representation of your data would be better than attempting a description.

Comment: The same row the formula was entered into, we can just work with the first row. So row 1

Comment: Where do the codes in Column A of sheet1 come from?

Comment: think of sheet one as an invoice and sheet 2 as a db

Comment: In B2 put `IF($A2<>"" ,Sheet2!A2,"")` then drag B2 to C2.  Then Drag both down.

Comment: But ultimately if there is no correlation between the two lists except position, why not simply copy and paste?

Comment: The content of my b and c columns depend on what code I have entered into the a column.

Comment: How?  There is no "a1" or "a2" on sheet2.

Comment: ok yea it should be a2 and a3, those exist on sheet2. a1 is a heading.

Comment: Please show a new picture of sheet2 that has those cells.

Comment: One last attempt.  In what column do we find a2,a3 on sheet2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you say 'think of sheet 2 as a db', then it should have key column to identify a record. The whole point is that sheet2 must also have 3 columns - code, description & price with list of all possible codes to be entered in sheet1.

Then in Sheet1 in B2 enter `=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!A:C,2,0)`
Then in Sheet1 in C2 enter `=VLOOKUP($A2,Sheet2!A:C,3,0)`

and drag down as required.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, let me help you.

Sheet1:

[image: Sheet1]

Sheet2:

[image: Sheet2]

The formula you need is

```
=Concatenate(Vlookup(A2;Sheet1!A:C;2;false);" - Price: $";Vlookup(A2;Sheet1!A:C;3;false))
```

Paste this in Sheet2 B2, and drag down.

bye!

Comment: Wait this is sort of the opposite of what I'm trying to do?

Comment: 1 want to type just the code into sheet one and then the description and price should be filled into columns b and c.

Comment: @StormMuller without vba a cell containing nothing will also show nothing... you cant type in anything in A1 and have an output at B1... thats simply impossible... you need to have any formula in B1 so the cell knows what to output...